# How to get graphObject from parsing JSON

Tags: json, graph, cytoscape.js

how can i get all nodes from cytoscape generated json?

i.e. i've that JSON :

```
{
  "elements" : {
"nodes" : [ {
  "data" : {
    "id" : "pipe2",
    "type" : "input",
    "filename" : "pipe2"
  },
  "position" : {
    "x" : 100,
    "y" : 100
  },
  "group" : "nodes",
  "removed" : false,
  "selected" : false,
  "selectable" : true,
  "locked" : false,
  "grabbable" : true,
  "classes" : ""
}, {
  "data" : {
    "id" : "pipe2sfdfsdf",
    "type" : "input",
    "filename" : "pipe2sfdfsdf"
  },
  "position" : {
    "x" : 100,
    "y" : 100
  },
  "group" : "nodes",
  "removed" : false,
  "selected" : false,
  "selectable" : true,
  "locked" : false,
  "grabbable" : true,
  "classes" : ""
}, {
  "data" : {
    "id" : "ProfileMandatory",
    "type" : "stage",
    "stageType" : "ProfileMandatory",
    "isWatchpoint" : "true"
  },
  "position" : {
    "x" : 100,
    "y" : 100
  },
  "group" : "nodes",
  "removed" : false,
  "selected" : false,
  "selectable" : true,
  "locked" : false,
  "grabbable" : true,
  "classes" : ""
} ]
},
"style" : [ {
"selector" : "node",
"style" : {
  "label" : "data(id)"
}
}, {
"selector" : "edge",
"style" : {
  "curve-style" : "bezier",
  "target-arrow-shape" : "triangle"
 }
}, {
"selector" : ".edgehandles-hover",
"style" : {
  "background-color" : "red"
}
}, {
"selector" : ".edgehandles-source",
"style" : {
  "border-width" : "2px",
  "border-color" : "red"
}
}, {
"selector" : ".edgehandles-target",
"style" : {
  "border-width" : "2px",
  "border-color" : "red"
}
}, {
"selector" : ".edgehandles-preview, .edgehandles-ghost-edge",
"style" : {
  "line-color" : "red",
  "target-arrow-color" : "red",
  "source-arrow-color" : "red"
}
} ],
 "zoomingEnabled" : true,
 "userZoomingEnabled" : true,
 "zoom" : 1,
 "minZoom" : 1.0E-50,
 "maxZoom" : 1.0E50,
"panningEnabled" : true,
"userPanningEnabled" : true,
"pan" : {
"x" : 0,
"y" : 0
},
"boxSelectionEnabled" : true,
"renderer" : {
"name" : "canvas"
}
}
```

and I want to retrieve informations from all nodes written in the json.
For instance i should get a list with those Node Java custom objects :

- pipe2
- pipe2sfdfsdf
- ProfileMandatory

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details? I'm not clear which versions of which software (Cytoscape or Cytoscape.js) you were using to create the file, which information you want and how you want to process it.

In JavaScript, you can get all nodes from your JSON, let's say it is saved to the variable json, with just `json.elements.nodes`. If you load this graph into Cytoscape.js, you get elements with specific IDs with `cy.getElementById()`.